# Edit "Checkout" button class

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to edit the class button on /checkout/cart/ that says "Go to Checkout". I know that section can be edited in "totals.phtml" but the button itself is embedded in a function called "renderTotals()" which I can't find.

I'm having issues with Google Tag Manager because I can't change the class of the button.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you'll find the code you're looking for in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/link.phtml`.